# Proof of Stieltjes moment problem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, moment-problem

The [Stieltjes moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem) consists in finding the conditions on a sequence $m_n$ such that
$$m_n = \int_0^\infty x^n d\mu(x)$$
for some positive measure $\mu$.

I am looking for a proof of this statement.

This seems to be mentioned between pp 1 and 2 of [these pdf notes](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/book/papers/jcmp.pdf), using continuous fractions, but the explanation is not very explicit and I don't quite understand the connection between continuous fractions and the problem at hand.
A note to this problem is also made in [Simon and Reed's *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics* (1972)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780125850018/methods-of-modern-mathematical-physics) (pag 145), but only in the form of an exercise to the reader.
I am aware that I could look up the original 1894 paper but I was hoping for a more recent exposition/proof.

Comment: [Simon](http://math.caltech.edu/papers/bsimon/p269.pdf) Theorem 1, p.4, proved using modern measure theory and operator theory.

Comment: a now removed answer suggested the following reference containing a full proof: Boas, JR, *THE STIELTJES MOMENT PROBLEM FOR FUNCTIONS
OF BOUNDED VARIATION* (1939) ([link to pdf](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1939-45-06/S0002-9904-1939-06992-9/S0002-9904-1939-06992-9.pdf)) (although it seems to me that the proof in that paper also relies on a proof in an even earlier paper)

Comment: That seems to be a generalization of the original problem (for monotonic functions). I did not read thoroughly to see if it had a proof for the original problem.